# Copy content of one list to another list of a different type

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, ienumerator

I am having trouble copying the contents of a `List<TemplateSection>` to `List<Section>`. These are defined as below:

**`List<TemplateSection>` is**:

```
public class TemplateSection
{
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public List<MyTemplateItem> MyTemplateItems { get; set; }
}

public class MyTemplateItem
{
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string ItemText { get; set; }
}
```

**`List<Section>` is:**

```
public class Section
{
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public List<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }
}
public class MyItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
    public string ItemValue { get; set; }
}
```

`ItemValue` does not need a value when it is copied or it could just be an empty string.

`List<TemplateSection>` is a list of sections and checkbox items in each section with a unique name for each checkbox. `List<Section>` is the values that are saved from the form when the user makes updates.

I have tried doing: `List<Section> listSection = listTemplateSection.Cast<Section>().ToList();` but it fails to cast.

I don't know how else to describe this other than providing the definitions here. Please help!

Comment: You can define an explicit cast operator or use something like automapper.

Comment: A `Cast` is for convertible types - how do you expect the compilter to know how to create a `Section` from a `TemplateSection`?

Comment: Your 2 types just have one property in common and the other properties only have the same names but different types. As far as the compiler is concerned, they have nothing in common.

Comment: It would really help if you explained why you want to cast a `List<TemplateSection>` to a `List<Section>`; they are totally unrelated. What do you expect for `((Section)templateSection).MyItems.ItemValue`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. I went with @NetMage's answer and that's what i was looking for. Sorry if the question was not clear enough. I have made some updates to it

Comment: @DourHighArch I have updated the question with what i was expecting `((Section)templateSection).MyItems.ItemValue` to be and the reason that i am trying to 'cast' this

Comment: @slayernoah Is there any reason you prefer cast to projection? I guess it centralizes the conversion (template instantiation) process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can't guess how to convert from `TemplateSection` to `Section`. You must explicity do it yourself:

```
var ans = myTemplateSelections.Select(aTemplate => new Section {
        SectionName = aTemplate.SectionName,
        MyItems = aTemplate.MyTemplateItems.Select(ti => new MyItem {
            ItemName = ti.ItemName,
            ItemText = ti.ItemText //,
            // ItemValue = ???
        }).ToList();
    };
```

Per a couple of comments, you can use `Cast` if you are willing to write your own conversion operators.

Change your template classes to include the conversion operators:

```
public class TemplateSection {
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public List<MyTemplateItem> MyTemplateItems { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator Section(TemplateSection src) {
        return new Section {
            SectionName = src.SectionName,
            MyItems = new List<MyItem>(src.MyTemplateItems.Cast<MyItem>())
        };
    }
}

public class MyTemplateItem {
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemText { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator MyItem(MyTemplateItem src) {
        return new MyItem {
            ItemName = src.ItemName,
            ItemText = src.ItemText
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can use `Cast`:

```
var sections = new List<Section>(myTemplateSections.Cast<Section>());
```

Comment: This is not casting but projection

Comment: Thanks! this is just what i was looking for! You are the best!

Answer (score 1):

C# does not provide [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), as you expect (it looks the same, so I should be able to cast it). Furthermore, C# allows [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) restrictions only on interfaces and delegates, which makes your use case complicated. And the `List<T>` is not covariant either (`IReadOnlyList` would be), so more complexity added. With inheritance, covariance and an interface you could do this:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<MySection>();

        list.Add(new MySection()
        {
            Items = new List<MyItem>()
            {
                new MyItem() { Name = "One", Text = "Two", Value = "Three" }
            }
        });

        // can access value here: list.First().Items.First().Value

        IEnumerable<ISection<TemplateItem>> genericList = list;

        foreach (ISection<TemplateItem> genericSection in genericList) 
        {
            // no value here
        }
    }

}

public interface ISection<out T> where T : TemplateItem
{

    string Name { get; }

    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }

}

public class TemplateSection<T> : ISection<T> where T : TemplateItem
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<T> ISection<T>.Items => Items;
}

public class TemplateItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class MySection : TemplateSection<MyItem>
{        

}

public class MyItem : TemplateItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The covariant `IEnumerable` (defined as `out T`) allows us to assign a `MySection` to a `ISection<T>` within the `IEnumerable`. I guess, there will be a more elegant way nevertheless.